# Working with BMP - loading and saving

Tags: c++, bmp

With friends we're trying to write app to work with BMP files and we're going to make it as simple as it could be for us, because we're just starting to learn C and C++. Copying was going good with new real size of lines but now I wanted to add grayscale effect and got another problem: the right side of the picture is moved to the left - check out pictures. What's causing this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;

void ReadBMP()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test2.bmp", "rb");
    FILE* w = fopen("zapis.bmp", "wb");

    if(f == NULL)
        throw "Argument Exception";

    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);
    fwrite(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, w);

    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Width: " << width << endl;
    cout << "Height: " << height << endl;



    int realwidth = 3*width+(4 - ((3*width)%4))%4;
    int volume = height * realwidth;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[volume];

    fwrite(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, w);

    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), volume, f);
    unsigned char color = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < volume; i+=3)
    {
        color = 0;
        color+=data[i]*0.114;
        color+=data[i+1]*0.587;
        color+=data[i+2]*0.299;
        data[i] = color;
        data[i+1] = color;
        data[i+2] = color;
    }


    fwrite(data, sizeof(unsigned char), volume, w);



    fclose(f);
    fclose(w);
    delete(data);
}

int main()
{
    ReadBMP();
    return 0;
}
```

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7vBL.png)

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELzjx.png)

Comment: To write binary data use `write()`, the `<<` operator does text formatting, even if the file was opened in binary mode.

Comment: changed to fwrite, still some problems

Comment: I actually meant `ofstream::write()`, but well ...

Comment: w.write(info, 54);
error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: If you are running this under Windows, you also need to specify "binary" mode for writing the output file: `fopen("zapis.bmp", "wb");`.  Without this, every time your program tries to write an octet with the value 0x0a, an extra 0x0d will be inserted before it in the file.

Comment: Thanks! That worked very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char info[54];
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);
// fwrite(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, w); --- comment this line !!!!!!! 

int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];
```

You're writing header to file twice unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for the size of the image data is wrong. First you need to find the pitch, by multiplying the width by the bytes per pixel (3 for a 24-bit image), and then rounding up to the nearest multiple of 4. Then multiply the pitch by the height;

```
int byte_width = width * 3;
int pitch = byte_width + (4 - byte_width % 4) % 4;
int volume = pitch * height;
```

Comment: @Ratka: There's a lot of other information in the BMP file format you are ignoring. For example, there may be other data between the header and the pixel data. You should look at the offset (4 byte integer, 10 bytes from the start) which tells you the exact location of the pixel data starting from the beginning of the file.

Comment: I've changed the formula but got another problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in my own code (that was written about 20 years ago) each line of the image is complemented by 0 or more empty bytes to align the start byte. It seems, your calculate wrong alignment.

Just copy & paste here:

```
unsigned short paddingSize;
unsigned short bitsPerLine = width * bitsPerPixel;

if(1 == bitsPerPixel || 4 == bitsPerPixel)
{
  if(bitsPerLine % 8)
    bitsPerLine += 8;

  paddingSize = (bitsPerLine/8) % 2;
}
else if(8 == bitsPerPixel)
  paddingSize = 0x0003 & ~((bitsPerLine/8) % 4 - 1);
else
  paddingSize = (bitsPerLine/8) % 2;
```

Real size of each line is `calculatedSize + paddingSize` where `calculatedSize` is exact size of line in bytes i.e. `ceil(bitsPerLine/8)` or `(bitsPerLine + 7)/8` ic C/C++.

What I can say about the code is it's debugged and it works. But I don't remember why all these checks here.

Comment: I know that each line has added "0" bytes at the end, but I don't get your way - why is it so compicated?

Comment: Cause there's not simple rule to detect padding. It's different dependent on different bits per plane.